# HTML Agility Pack is selecting nodes that should not be in the scope

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

```
        // From File
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);

        foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[@class='crow']"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.OuterHtml);
            foreach (HtmlNode innerNode in node.SelectNodes(@"//a|//span"))
            {
                var Link = innerNode.GetAttributeValue("href", "no Link");
                var TextOrDate = innerNode.InnerText;
                File.AppendAllText($@"{i}.txt", Link + "\r\n");
                File.AppendAllText($@"{i}.txt", TextOrDate + "\r\n");
            }
```

doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[@class='crow']") is selecting 100 results per page that show up when I check the node.OuterHtml, however when I check the innerNode.OuterHtml its catching anchor tags that are not in the node at all, but rather else where in the html page. Why isn't the //a|//span limited to anchor and span tags inside the scope of node?

This is how a crow block of html looks:

```
<div class="crow">
    <div>something</div>
    <div class="atitle">
        <a href="link" target="_blank" title="title">[title]</a>&nbsp;
        <a href="link" target="_blank" title="name">name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sj">
        <span>date</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `.` : `node.SelectNodes(@".//a|.//span")`

Comment: THANKS!!! That cursed dot was making me crazy.